# Convergence of the product of two Random Functions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

$lim_{t\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(|g(X(t))|>\epsilon)=0$,

$f(X(t))=\mathbb{1}_{({X(t)}\neq{0})}$

I want to show $f(X(t))g(X(t))$ coverage in probability to 0. Just wondering if it is possible, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(|f(X(t))g(X(t))| >\epsilon) \leq P(g(X(t))| >\epsilon)\to 0$. (I have just used the fact that $f$ is bounded by $1$).

Comment: thank you sir, I was wondering if I were to change the first line to "$lim_{t\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(|\frac{1}{g(X(t))}|>\epsilon)=0$,  here g() is any finite polynomial function". If this would still be true or not.

Comment: No, $\frac 1 {g(X(T)) \to 0 $  in probability will not work.